# Explanation for this stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to understand a stored procedure, but I don't get it. I'm totally new to stored procedures. I have ordered a book about T-SQL, but it didn't arrive yet. I'm literally stuck.

Can someone please explain to me what the following stored procedure exactly does?

[image: Stored procedure]

I know that ALTER stands for, modifying the stored procedure, `@Region` and `@State` are the parameters.

Begin is where the stored procedure starts

When do you have to use '' , like in the first select statement?

What exaclty is the LO. and PR. ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: While you are waiting for your T-SQL book to show up, you can use Google or YouTube for some basic TSQL lessons.

Comment: The `'Alle'` is a **string literal** which has to be put into single quotes (`' ... '`). And the `LO` and `PR` are **table alias**es, so that you can refer to those tables with a short (hopefully meaningful!) alias instead of having to type the whole table name over and over again

Answer (score 0):

LO and PR are "placeholder" or "alias" for the table dim_LOcation and lookup_city_PRovider